# What is $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2-\pi)??$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

I'm understanding transcendental extension and I've found this question: Find $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2-\pi)$.

I guess the answer is $\mathbb{Q}$, but I still didn't get the proof. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2-\pi)$ then there exists $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.t

$$\alpha = \frac {p(\pi^2)}{q(\pi^2)} = \frac{r(\pi^2-\pi)}{s(\pi^2-\pi)}$$.

It could help: If we call $\alpha = \phi(\pi)$, since $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$ we have $\phi(\pi) = \phi(-\pi)$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2- \pi)$ we have $\phi(\pi) =  \phi(1-\pi)$.

Do you have any hint about that??

Comment: Do you mean to compute $\mathbb Q(\pi^2)\cap \mathbb Q(\pi^2 - \pi)$? As written, the problem can be easily solved as $\pi^2-\pi \in \mathbb Q(\pi)$.

Comment: I've made a typo, I mean $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2-\pi)$...

Comment: How $\pi^2 - \pi \in \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ helps??

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$ a minimal field containing both all elements from $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\pi^2$?

Comment: I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, but I don't know what is the relation you mean

Comment: @LevonMinasian Yes that is how that field is defined. And OP, my initial comment was before your edit, when it read $\mathbb Q(\pi) \cap \nathbb Q(\pi^2-\pi)$, which is just $\mathbb Q(\pi^2-\pi)$. I don't have a solution to the corrected problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your helpful observation is on point. First though, for psychological reasons, lets think of rational functions of $x$ rather than of $\pi$. There is no harm here as $\mathbb{Q}(x)\cong \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Hence, we have a rational function $\phi(x)$ with the property that $\phi(-x) = \phi(x)$ and $\phi(1-x) = \phi(x)$. Consequently, $\phi(x) = \phi(1-x) = \phi(x-1)$, and $\phi$ is a periodic function. However, the only rational periodic functions are the constant functions: Suppose $\phi = p(x)/q(x)$ is nonconstant, $p(x)$, $q(x)$ relatively prime polynomials. Without loss of generality, we may suppose the degree of $p$ is positive (otherwise replace $\phi$ with $1/\phi$). Then $\phi$ has a positive finite number of zeros, and is not periodic.